# Intersection of 2 arrays of hashes by hash value (such as id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, activerecord

In my rails app, I have a user model and a linkedin_connection model. Linkedin_connection belongs to user and user has_many linkedin_connections.

What's the best way to create a crossover array of connections between user1 and user2?

============== EDIT ============== EDIT ============== EDIT ==============

I realized that this is sort of a different problem than I originally thought. I have 2 arrays of hashes. Each hash has an id element. How can I find the intersection of two hashes by their ids?

Example

```
user1.linkedin_connections => [{id: "123xyz", name: "John Doe"}, {id: "789abc", name: "Alexander Supertramp"}]

user2.linkedin_connections => [{id: "456ijk", name: "Darth Vader"}, {id: "123xyz", name: "John Doe"}]

cross_connections => [{id: "123xyz", name: "John Doe"}]
```

How can I calculate "cross_connections?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the *intersection* of the two arrays.  In ruby, that's easy, using the `&` operator:

```
crossover_connections = user1.linkedin_connections.to_a & user2.linkedin_connections.to_a
```